# Error while connecting to oracle using oracle provider for ole db

Tags: oracle, oledb

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=system;Data Source=192.168.1.11;FetchSize=200;CacheType=Memory;OLEDB.NET=True;SPPrmsLOB=True;NDatatype=True;
```

this is my connection string to connect to oracle database,while establishing connection,error is thrown for rowset does not support scrolling backwards

what to do?

Comment: Can you open your connection from your front-end program? What is the front-end code? Where are you getting the error and what exactly is your problem? As per your description, the error you are complaining about has nothing to do with the connection string.

Comment: it's an application to connect to oracle db,i have tried with MSDAORA,MSoledb these throw no error i get the result,only with Oracle provider for ole db am getting this error